# Creating a Table with Rows and Columns in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview, uibutton

I would like to create a table in iOS that have some rows and columns. We also have an option to add amounts to the table. A screenshot of the sample table is posted below:
[image]

The cells needs to be editable. Is there a way to implement this using the default UITableView in iOS. Or Is it a good to create it using buttons or textfields etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would not be an easy solution but you can use a rotated (horizontal) `UITableView` inside each cell of a table view (vertical) just like the Pulse app. Using only labels makes it easy to manage but the "excel" look could be harder if you're planning handling events like selecting rows, sort...

Here's a two part tutorial on how to use horizontal tables (http://www.raywenderlich.com/) :

[part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) - [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

Answer (score 3):

In ios6 you can use a `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to archive this. A `UICollectionView` works very similar to a `UITableView`, but gives you more control over how the cells should be displayed and aligned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. I need to support iOS 5 also.

Comment: For pre-ios6 i dont know a easy solution supported by the framework. If you need a huge amount of columns/rows you will probably need to implement your own reusable logic to avoid performance problems. If you have only a limited amount of cells you should be able to use a ScrollView with textfields.

Comment: UICollectionViewFlowLayout seems to only allow Horizontal OR Vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source solution on GitHub that supports iOS 4.3+ if you are still looking for options. I haven't actually used it, but it looks like works like UICollectionView.

[PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)

Answer (score 0):

I created a table structure similar to this using tableview and scrollview .Think that could be helpful to you

You could get the sample project here

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-brvnZfBXwTU21VbmNNcnRSU2M&usp=sharing