# With IOS, is there a way of making a proper table with rows and columns?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been trying to find a way of creating a table, with rows and columns, for iOS. The UiTableView is basically a tree-structured list like this
[Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/tv_plain_style.jpg), but because it's called a table view, it hijacks any attempt to search for a proper table.

There are a couple answers that suggest very clunky ways of doing it, like this [SE Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565515/creating-a-table-with-rows-and-columns-in-ios), but it's quite old. Has the situation changed since this question was asked?

Comment: Nope, nothing has changed since that question.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using UITableView by simply designing custom UITableViewCells that are segmented into columns. All the custom rows together certainly give the appearance of a multi-column table. When any of your data in a column or row updates, you re-render the tableView or have each row in charge of its own re-rendering (i.e. via an NSNotificationCenter message), and the whole experience for the user is as a multi-column table. If you setup your table's data as a separate row-column data model, it's pretty easy to get all the individual cells to go where they need to go with your custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: How do you align the columns in each UITableViewCell? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: The columns are just subviews on the table cell, either labels or real UIViews, and in Interface Builder (no code needed) you just setup their positions.

Answer (score -2):

take a UITableView and on tableRow take 3 view of(width=1 and height=row height), each view ill be at equal distance from another one. and take label between these view at end it ill look like a table with rows and column